# Does any MDM provide privacy assurances to the end user?

Tags: ios

I'm a former network admin who deployed and configured MDM solutions. I recall being able to do things like

- List all the applications on a device (including 3rd party apps)
- Get device IP information, which could be used in geo tracking
- Get the advertising ID on iOS, or other static identifiers  that can be theoretically correlated with advertising
- other information I may not want to freely offer without consent

My question is, does any MDM offer privacy assurances to end users?

Does Android or iOS offer any OS protections from excessive PII disclosure? Perhaps as a limited MDM profile?

Comment: Consent may be a valid issue for discussion, but the model of security that MDM applies to is for the protection of an organization, not an individual.